# Java EE roadmap and learning material

Tags: jakarta-ee

I have been programming with DOTNET( enterprise applications) for the last 6 years. Although I had studied Java as a language in colleges I am novice to Java EE.

Although it is difficult to choose between DotNet Vs Java EE, knowing both are not bad. So I am planning to start learning Java EE.

Will you kindly let me know what are the things that I should learn in Java EE, Application Servers, tech for Enterprise Integration etc as there are hell lots of options in Java EE and any books I must follow to start with.

Answer (score 14):

This is a very general question to answer, but here is the order that I would learn:

- Learn about how the server works. The simplest one would probably be looking at [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/). This would serve as the basis for other Java EE Application servers
- Next you need the basics on how a Java EE server accepts a request and gives a response. This would be the [Servlet](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/servlet/index.html) as well as [Java Server Pages(JSP)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagx.html).
- [Java Beans](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnair.html) is fundamental for Java EE. It represents the object model that you will use across the application
- If you are interested in messaging, you should familiarize yourself with [JMS](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncdq.html)
- To connect to various databases, you need to know how to use [JDBC](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/). The tutorial will get you up and running pretty soon
- Once you learn those, there are a few frameworks that people use in the Java EE world. You could pick and choose once you have understood the basics. Few example of well known frameworks:

  - [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) is well known ORM framework for Java enabling further abstraction over JDBC
  - [Spring Framework](http://www.springsource.com/developer/spring) used by many providing Inversion of Control and [Dependency Injection](http://www.vogella.de/articles/SpringDependencyInjection/article.html)
  - [Apache Strut](http://struts.apache.org/) provides a framework for developing MVC app. Note, that people normally choose between Spring Framework MVC or Strut. You are welcome to learn both
  - [JavaServer Faces(JSF)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/documentation/index-137726.html) is yet another option for building your application. I have not used this one personally
  - If you are into building web services, you should look at [JAX-RS](http://www.vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html) or [Restlet Framework](http://www.restlet.org/)

There are many other frameworks out there for building Java EE applications. You should get to know the basics and then pick and choose which framework that you want to learn to extend the basics. I, by no means, have not put every single framework in the options, but it should be enough to get your started

As for books, there is no single book out there that covers all options but the core of Java EE is available to buy/download/view online. You could get them at [Java EE Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/index.html) or [as printed book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137081855) That should give you plenty to learn initially. Another book that people are recommending is [Head First Servlets and JSP](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596005405/)

Comment: thanks for the info. It is nice, I will be highly obliged if u can name any book/books etc which will help me to learn the materials from a single location. Thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately you couldn't learn from a single location. Each of the topic above is pretty big and will take time to learn and no one has put all material in one place. I will try to put few up to help out

Comment: Check out J2EE Tutorial (http://java.sun.com/docs/books/j2eetutorial/index.html). You could buy the book, download or view it online. It covers all major J2EE topics outside of the external frameworks. This should be enough to get you going

Comment: You should accept the answer if this has been helpful to let others know. There is a tick mark next to the answer